# Response is getting false in Twitter Twitterizer automatic update the status

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

When attempting to post a tweet using the Twitterizer library, the TwitterStatus.Update method is always returning false, even though I believe I am providing the correct values.

```
var oauth_consumer_key = "[REDACTED]";
var oauth_consumer_secret = "[REDACTED]";


if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
{
    OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
        oauth_consumer_key,
        oauth_consumer_secret,
        Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

    Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
        reqToken.Token));
}
else
{
    string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
    string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

    var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
        oauth_consumer_key,
        oauth_consumer_secret,
        requestToken,
        pin);

    OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
    {
        AccessToken = tokens.Token,
        AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
        ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
        ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
    };

    TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken,"Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

    if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
    {
        Response.Write("we did it!");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("it's all bad.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your next step should be to query the properties of the response object to see if it includes a helpful error message.

Comment: Actually I am getting no error regarding this issue. I just want to show "Testing!! It works (hopefully)." this string on the twitter by this method. Can you specify what you want to say?

Comment: The TwitterResponse object has an "ErrorMessage" property that may contain information about why the Update method is returning False.